# ImportError: No module named 'tensorrt'

Tags: linux, python-3.x, tensorrt

I installed TensorRT on my VM using the Debian Installation. If I run "dpkg -l | grep TensorRT" I get the expected result:

```
ii  graphsurgeon-tf                                             5.0.2-1+cuda10.0                           amd64        GraphSurgeon for TensorRT package
ii  libnvinfer-dev                                              5.0.2-1+cuda10.0                           amd64        TensorRT development libraries and headers
ii  libnvinfer-samples                                          5.0.2-1+cuda10.0                           all          TensorRT samples and documentation
ii  libnvinfer5                                                 5.0.2-1+cuda10.0                           amd64        TensorRT runtime libraries
ii  python3-libnvinfer                                          5.0.2-1+cuda10.0                           amd64        Python 3 bindings for TensorRT
ii  python3-libnvinfer-dev                                      5.0.2-1+cuda10.0                           amd64        Python 3 development package for TensorRT
ii  tensorrt                                                    5.0.2.6-1+cuda10.0                         amd64        Meta package of TensorRT
ii  uff-converter-tf                                            5.0.2-1+cuda10.0                           amd64        UFF converter for TensorRT package
```

Yet when I try to import it in python I get:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'tensorrt'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to import in python 2 or python 3?

Comment: I'm using python 3

Comment: Please try importing uff, and tensorflow before tensorRT.

Comment: Was your problem solved?

Comment: Don't have the environment to test it on anymore, but at the time when I imported uff it wasn't found

Comment: Me too on the same boat. Installed everything, 

with       dpkg -l | grep TensorRT, 
I can see python package installed, too but doesn't show up.

Comment: Same here. What version of python3 are you running?

Answer (score 9):

just run these commands:

```
pip install nvidia-pyindex
pip install nvidia-tensorrt
```

Comment: This solved the problem for me. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

i had same error, solved it by installing following 2 packages:

```
# from TensorRT Tar Package ( TensorRT-5.0.2.6/python/ ) 
pip3 install tensorrt-5.0.2.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl  
# pycuda
pip3 install pycuda 

# libnvinfer 5.0.2-1
# libnvinfer-dev 5.0.2-1
# libnvinfer-samples 5.0.2-1
# python3-libnvinfer 5.0.2-1
# python3-libnvinfer-dev 5.0.2-1
# tensorrt 5.0.2.6
```

Answer (score 2):

two suggestions:

1. make sure that your TensorRT is added do your path
   (LD_LIBRARY_PATH)
2. if you have both python 2 and python3 installed, check for
   package installation in pip list and/or pip3 list

Answer (score 0):

You need to import in python3 environment as you seems to have installed TensorRT for python3. So it does not get import on python2.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a **virtual environment**, go to the following path to check if it exists.

```
(deepNN) agxxavier@agxxavier-desktop:~/miniforge3/envs/deepNN/lib/python3.6/site-packages$ ls
```

Use the following command to check where tensorrt.so is located

```
(base) agxxavier@agxxavier-desktop:~$ sudo find / -iname "*tensorrt*"
```

and to create a soft connection in your virtual environment.

```
(deepNN) agxxavier@agxxavier-desktop:~/miniforge3/envs/deepNN/lib/python3.6/site-packages$ ln -s /usr/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorrt/tensorrt.so tensorrt.so
```