# importing tensorrt gives module not found error

Tags: python-3.8, nvidia-jetson, tensorrt, jetson-xavier, tensorrt-python

The import of tenosrrt gives an error of module not found. Here are some commands I ran on my terminal. I am working on **jetson xavier nx developer tool kit**. Tensorrt is installed by default with  jetpack flash
Python version:3.8
tensorrt version: tensorrt  (8.5.2.2-1+cuda11.4)
Device: Jetson Xavier NX

`$ dpkg -L tensorrt`

```
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/tensorrt
/usr/share/doc/tensorrt/changelog.Debian
/usr/share/doc/tensorrt/copyright
```

`$ sudo apt-get install tensorrt`

`Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading state information... Done **tensorrt is already the newest version (8.5.2.2-1+cuda11.4)**. 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 205 not upgraded.`

`$ python`
Python 3.8.10 (default, May 26 2023, 14:05:08)
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
`>>> import tensorrt`

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorrt'

I have tried solutions from [ImportError: No module named 'tensorrt'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55557912/importerror-no-module-named-tensorrt)

$ pip install nvidia-tensorrt
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://pypi.ngc.nvidia.com
Collecting nvidia-tensorrt
Downloading nvidia-tensorrt-0.0.1.dev5.tar.gz (7.9 kB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [17 lines of output]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 2, in 
File "", line 34, in 
File "/tmp/pip-install-19tykmvn/nvidia-tensorrt_b3ad27f5428d46f594cd069dee9419ee/setup.py", line 150, in 
raise RuntimeError(open("ERROR.txt", "r").read())
RuntimeError:
The package you are trying to install is only a placeholder project on PyPI.org repository.
This package is hosted on NVIDIA Python Package Index.

```
  This package can be installed as:
```

```` ``` $ pip install nvidia-pyindex $ pip install nvidia-tensorrt ````
```

```
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install python3-libnvinfer-dev
```

helped me solve the problem.
you can also refer to [https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/tensorrt/archives/tensorrt-722/pdf/TensorRT-Installation-Guide.pdf#:~:text=Go%20to%3A%20https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.nvidia.com%2Ftensorrt.%202.%20Click%20Download%20Now.%20Select,5.%20Click%20the%20package%20you%20want%20to%20install](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/tensorrt/archives/tensorrt-722/pdf/TensorRT-Installation-Guide.pdf#:%7E:text=Go%20to%3A%20https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.nvidia.com%2Ftensorrt.%202.%20Click%20Download%20Now.%20Select,5.%20Click%20the%20package%20you%20want%20to%20install).

for more details.

Answer (score 0):

On my Jetson Xavier NX with Jetpack installed

```bash
$ python3 -c "import tensorrt as trt; print(trt.__path__)"
['/usr/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorrt']
$ dpkg -S /usr/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorrt
python3-libnvinfer: /usr/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorrt
```

So you should install `python3-libnvinfer` to get `tensorrt` module in Python.